# IOS selector does not execute

Tags: ios, cocoa, selector

The @selector(apiRequest:didFinishWithData:) will not execute even though the fetcher does finish with data.  I have tried to debug the problem with breakpoints. The method I call from the selector is not executed and bypassed as I cycle through the breakpoints. Is this because selectors do not run on the main thread? How can I correct this?

```
   OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
   [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                        delegate:self
               didFinishSelector:@selector(apiRequest:didFinishWithData:)
                 didFailSelector:@selector(apiRequest:didFailWithError:)];



   (void)apiRequest:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data {
   if (ticket.didSucceed) {
   NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSLog(responseBody);
    //could use this to implement errors
   NSError* error;
   NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                         JSONObjectWithData:data //1
                         options:kNilOptions
                         error:&error];}
   }
```

Comment: I assume that `didFinishWithData` is declared as `- (void)apiRequest:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data` with the leading "`-`"? I'm suspect it was just a pasting issue, but wanted to make sure.

Comment: Are you sure that `ticket.didSucceed`? Entire `apiRequest:didFinishWithData:` body is guarded with this condition.